# get HTML DOM index by Id

Tags: html, dom, indexing

Eg. `document.form[0].elements[23]` will result some input `<input id = test2>` .

I need to get that `23` index value by id or name = 'test2' like
`var n = document.getElementById('test2').getDOMNodeIndex(); // n = 23`

Comment: Why do you need the index? Once you do `document.getElementById('test2')` you have the element at that index so you don't need to look it up again by index....

Comment: For new JS, `document.querySelector('#test2')`.

Comment: I want to iterate some dom elements aprox 10 elements which will come after #test2 . whenever the #test2 is changed... all the 10 elements have to be changed... I don't want to use document.querySelector('1') .. to all the way to 10 elements repeatedly...If i get that index I can achieve the dom operation with single loop
.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be slightly clunky, but it works as demonstrated below.

I generated 25 input elements and gave them unique IDs.

Then I selected a random index among the [`Form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) and printed it to the console.

Then I iterated over the `form.elements` until I found the matching [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) values ([JSON.stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)). When a match is found, return that index.

```js
const theForm = document.forms[0];
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * theForm.elements.length);
console.log(randomIndex);
const theInput = theForm.elements[randomIndex];
const formElementsIndexOf = (form, element) => {
  let search = JSON.stringify(element.outerHTML);
  for (let i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    if (JSON.stringify(form.elements[i].outerHTML) === search) {
      return i;
    }
  }
};
console.log(formElementsIndexOf(theForm, theInput));
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text0">
  <input type="text" id="text1">
  <input type="text" id="text2">
  <input type="text" id="text3">
  <input type="text" id="text4">
  <input type="text" id="text5">
  <input type="text" id="text6">
  <input type="text" id="text7">
  <input type="text" id="text8">
  <input type="text" id="text9">
  <input type="text" id="text10">
  <input type="text" id="text11">
  <input type="text" id="text12">
  <input type="text" id="text13">
  <input type="text" id="text14">
  <input type="text" id="text15">
  <input type="text" id="text16">
  <input type="text" id="text17">
  <input type="text" id="text18">
  <input type="text" id="text19">
  <input type="text" id="text20">
  <input type="text" id="text21">
  <input type="text" id="text22">
  <input type="text" id="text23">
  <input type="text" id="text24">
</form>
```